# Extend javascript function into dynamically loaded file

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, load

this is the problem:
I' have a page with some .js files embedded, in this files there are some javascript functions.
Now, if I load some content into my page using jQuery load function, the functions before mentioned not affect the new included elements...
What can I do?

```
function say_ciao(){
    alert('Ciao!!!');
}

$('#home_button').on('click', function(){
    say_ciao();
});

$('#load_button').on('click', function(){
   $('#loader').load('externalpage.php');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ppvpp/

Thanks alot for your answers and sorry for my english!

Comment: What action are you performing in functions? Provide some code

Comment: create a http://jsfiddle.net for your scenario if possible

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to achieve and what is your problem. If you mean you're adding elements dynamically to the page through Javascript and you're unable to trigger events on those elements, then you need to look at delegated events...

Comment: Use event delegation.

Comment: Q:What can I do? A:Provide real example from your attempts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use event delegation. If the user clicks an element, it'll 'click' all parent elements of that element too. You can use this behaviour:

Instead of

```
$('#home_button').on('click', function(){
```

use:

```
$('selector for parent of that button').on('click', '#home_button', function() {
  ...
}
```

The problem is that on the moment you call your function, it'll bind the handler to all elements it matches *at that point*. If you add a new element that matches that selector, it won't have the handler attached to it (the moment you attached the handler to the elements has already passed). The trick is to attach the handler to a parent object instead (an object that doesn't get dynamically added), and only execute the function if the clicked element matches the selector string in the second argument of `.on()`. See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/).